# Is there a difference in syntax between OLE and Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I ran this morning in a problem I can't find answer anywhere, so now I'm just asking to people who might have more knowledge than me on the subject ;). So here's the problem, when I'm executing a certain query in MS Access I got the rows I am expecting to receive, no problem there. However, when I run the exact same command (copy-paste) in an OleDbCommand object, it doesn't return anything. My datatable is empty. I'll copy the query so you might spot a difference in the syntax I might not be aware of:

```
odbCommand = New OleDbCommand( _
    "SELECT IDTemps, NomEmploye, HreAllouees, HreReelles, TauxHoraire, " & _
    " Description, NoProjet_Short, NoJob, Type FROM TableA " & _
    " WHERE NoProjet_Short = '13015' " & _
    " AND Type = 'DessinE' ", odbConnection)

    dbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(odbCommand)
    odbConnection.Open()
    dbAdapter.Fill(dtTable)
```

Note: this is the core of the code, did not paste the error management (since I have no error, my DataTable is just empty, and should not be).

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Are you sure that  `NoProjet_Short` is a text data field ?

Comment: @Steve Yes the field NoProjet_Short is a text field in the database.

Comment: Could you check the connection? Is it possible that you are working with a different access file? (Pay attention to database files in the project working folder and database in the bin\debug directory)

Comment: @Steve The connection string points to the right database. I was executing another query on this command earlier but I had to change it, and it's not working now (the one I posted). That's why, to me, it points to a difference between the way Ole process the query and Access. Just like Access and SQL Server syntax differences.

Comment: Possible, but not for this query. It is a basic select without any fancy construct that could be interpreted only by Access. It should work as is. Another option is in the where condition (no record with values required) but I think you have already checked this

Comment: @Steve When I remove the " AND Type = 'DessinE' " statement from the query, it works and I get some result (more than I want. but I get something). The other guys who deleted his answer suggested that Type might be a reserved word? What you think about that? Never heard of it in SQL.

Comment: If it was a problem of reserved keywords you will get a Syntax error, try to readd the condition but using `Type LIKE 'DessinE'`

Comment: @Steve Well, again, it still returns 0 records when I execute it with OleDbCommand and 4 using Access...:/. I think I'll get a stress ball, my mouse doesn't like to be sqeezed like that.

Comment: Have you tried with a different Type value. Perhaps you have some character that gets in the way (accents for example), and well if it possible I would like to test with your database

Comment: Yes, the field name Type is going to be a problem. Try renaming your column or see if you can delimit it like this:

[TableA].[Type]

Comment: @Steve I managed to narrow down to one think : it doesn't like value that looks the same. In the database, I need to make the difference between Dessin, and DessinE and DessinM. I can do it using Access but it seems like it's not doable inside OleDb. I'll find a way to give them an id instead. If you want to see the database, how can I do that?

Comment: @dmarietta I tried to use [Type] and renaming it LeType but none of this seems to work.

Comment: You could upload your db to a sharing service like SkyDrive, GDrive, Mediafire, DropBox and share here the link.

Comment: @Steve I uploaded it on Dropbox, here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/95no2dvptjh8kjw/DataProjetCopy%20-%202013-03-19.zip  . The database only have one table since it's only an old backup but the data from this table did not change.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but it works as expected. I have used LinqPAD to create a scratch VB Program from the code above. The only thing that change is the connection string that points to my temp folder. I can find 4 record in your db. - Working with ACE data provider and Office 2010 64bit installed, Win7 64bit.

Comment: @Steve I'm using Access 2000 and Windows XP, Provider is Jet 4.0. I'm having problem only with the "AND" statement. When I remove it, it's ok, whether I use one or the other condition :(. It just don't want me to do both.

Comment: @Steve I am SO embarrassed right now...I just figured out why it was not working. On the first window of my application, the user can chose whether he wants to use the local or the server database (see where I'm going?). By default it's set to server because the application will be use primarily at work and sometimes at home. But all the changes I made to the database was, on the local side. I'm so sorry to have wasted your time :/. But thanks we have show that (yet) OleDb interprets the queries as it should. Thanks a lot Steve :)

Comment: Post your findings as an answer. It is still an educational history for those who read this question. Morale, toujours vérifier votre connexion. Good work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well after a complete day of testing a LOT of different data, table configuration, many many change in my query, I finally found the answer to my problem. Steve helped me lot in this one in testing with actual database by showing me te path to the Holy Grail : the damn connection string ;).

My connection string was actually good, but I have many of them and the database I was pointing to in my VB.NET application was not the one I was modifying using MS Access.

Final word on this: always double-check the ConnectionString (and thx Steve) :)